# Go type automatically converting when it seems like it shouldn't

Tags: go, types, casting

Sorry for the ambiguous title. I'm not getting a compiler error when I believe that I should, based on creating a new type and a function that takes an argument of that type.

The example:

```
package search

//Some random type alias
type Search string

//Takes a string and returns Search
func NewSearch(s string) Search {
   return Search(s)
}

//This is where things are getting weird
//Returns an int just for arbitrary testing
func PrintSearch(s Search) int{
    return 5
}
```

Now my assumption would be, if I created an object using `NewSearch`, I would be able to pass it to PrintSearch and have everything run as expected, but if I passed PrintSearch a primitive string, it should not compile.  I am not experiencing this behavior.

The main code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    ".../search" //no need to type the whole path here
)

func main() {
   SearchTerm := search.NewSearch("Test")
   StringTerm := "Another test"

   fmt.Println(search.PrintSearch(SearchTerm)) // This should print 5
   fmt.Println(search.PrintSearch(StringTerm)) // This should throw a compiler error, but it is not
}
```

It seems like if I write the type and the function in the same package as main, everything works as I'd expect? As in, it throws a compiler error. Is there something I've missed about cross-package type coercion?

Comment: You don't need to convert the the type when it's assignable: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability

Comment: So, what is the specific usecase for `type Something string` if you'd get the same type-safety from just using `string` itself?

Comment: "x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a named type." I quote the doc JimB linked. Search underlying type is string and string is an unnamed type.

Comment: It is about the method set which is different. Using string as an example makes a _very_ bad example here.

Comment: @JimB Then why do you have to convert it when the type and function definitions are also in the main package, instead of search package?

Comment: @thisisnotabus I've just repeated your example and I'm getting `cannot use StringTerm (type string) as type a.Search in argument to a.PrintSearch`. Are you sure you aren't using constants in your original code?

Comment: @jussius: I think I see what you're asking now, but that _does_ fail in the main package too: https://play.golang.org/p/xXk5tTdTe4 -- like Ainar-G asked, are you using constants to test?

Comment: @JimB It throws a compiler error if everything is done in the same package. As in, if I define the Search type and PrintSearch method in the same package as main/as they're being used, I get a compiler error. If I define them in a separate package and import them, I do not. I am definitely not using constants.

Comment: @Ainar-G If you repeated it all in one package/in main, the compiler will throw an exception. Try moving the Search type/the PrintSearch method to its own package and import it in main.

Comment: @thisisnotabus: no, it throws an error in both cases, so I'm still confused as to what you're doing. Maybe you're not importing what you think you are? Please try to make a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: @thisisnotabus No, I did it in two packages. But if you used constants instead of variables, it would work just as you described.

Comment: @Ainar-G unless `:=` declares constants, I am not using constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can simplify this example a bit further ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/i6_d1zTGwn)):

```
package main

type Foo string

type Bar int

func main() {
    var f Foo = "foo"
    var b Bar = 1

    println(f, b)
}
```

This is explained in the [spec's assignability section](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability).

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to
>   T") in any of these cases:
>
> - x's type is identical to T.
> - x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a named type.
> - T is an interface type and x implements T.
> - x is a bidirectional channel value, T is a channel type, x's type V and T have identical element types, and at least one of V or T is not a named type.
> - x is the predeclared identifier nil and T is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type.
> - x is an untyped constant representable by a value of type T.